# How to Delete PXResultset

Tags: acumatica

i have the following code in my Graph:

```
foreach (CQPaycheckJournalDtl erredPaycheckJournal in ExistingPaycheckJournalDtl)
            {
                payroll.PaycheckJournalDtls.Delete(erredPaycheckJournal);

            }
```

ExistingPaycheckJournalDtl is a PXResultSet and i would like to delete it more effeciently and faster. is there a way to delete all elements in PXResultset without iterating through the items?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of or that another solution wouldn't perform the same iteration to delete the contents of the result set in the cache. What you have posted seems like a valid/preferred solution.

As an alternative, we have deleted data using PXDatabase.Delete to delete in bulk. So if you do not need to fill in a PXResultSet or rely on the cache of your graph, you can using something similar to the following example found in an AP integrity check process:

```
PXDatabase.Delete<APHistory>(
new PXDataFieldRestrict("VendorID", PXDbType.Int, 4, vend.BAccountID, PXComp.EQ),
new PXDataFieldRestrict("FinPeriodID", PXDbType.Char, 6, minPeriod, PXComp.GE)
);
```

Just search "PXDatabase.Delete" in the Acumatica source and there are plenty of examples. Note the use of PXConnectionScope and PXTransactionScope with the PXDatabase calls. Also note as Dmitry mentioned the attributes are ignored when using PXDatabase calls. Using PXDatabase has its special use cases so beware.

Comment: One should be very careful when using PX.Database operations. No business logic defined in the attributes/graph will work this way. E.g. if you have some document with lines, lines will not be deleted automatically on deleting header if you use PXDatabase.Delete. Otherwise, if you use regular cache deleting mechanism, PXParent attribute will automatically delete child objects on deleting parent one.

Comment: I would agree with Dmitry. Its a special use case when using PXDatabase calls. For us its a long running process that we clear out the last processed data.We delete the entire contents of the table.